# Linux sql server Docker stops after few seconds

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

This is the command I execute but the container just stop after few seconds: `docker run -it -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=dockermssql" -p 1433:1433 -v sqlvlm:/var/opt/mssql --name sql1 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your password (e.g. `dockermssql`) doesn't meet the [complexity requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017). So try adding a non-alphanumeric characters such as exclamation point (`!`).

To check for errors, run: `docker logs ID` (where `ID` is container ID from `docker ps`), or run container without `-d`.

Comment: In my case I had to restart docker desktop to see the right logs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove detatched mode "**-d**" so it runs in "foreground" mode, this should then give you your stdout, stderror etc to your terminal and you may see some errors logged which can hopefully point you in the right direction.